# transfer values of select boxes to hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three select boxes, one to select the year, another one for the month and the last one for the day. My goal is to have them automatically inserted into one hidden field (resulting in e.g. 2012-07-16) which is the main "date" field and that get's stored into the database.

Does anyone have an idea how this can be best achieved? Some advise would be highly appreciated, thank you very much, Patrick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#year, #month, #day').change(function() {
    $('#date').val($('#year').val()+'-'+$('#month').val()+'-'+$('#ay').val())
});
```

Comment: WOW - thank you so much Mihai Stancu, this is outstanding and very much appreaciated - thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Working example using plain javascript, u may change it to jquery.

http://jsfiddle.net/R3yeX/